# Updating sub sub documents not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a app where I am trying to add contact records to a user "profile" document, where each record has arrays/subdocuments for multiple phone number and email addresses.

So the Profile Schema looks like this:

```
var ContactSchema = require('./contact');
var UserSchema = new Schema({

    first_name:{
      type: String
    },
    last_name:{
      type: String
    },
    contacts:[ContactSchema]
});
```

The ContactSchema looks like this:

```
var ContactSchema = new Schema({

    contact_name:{
      type: String
    },
    contact_age:{
      type: String
    },
    phones:[{
       phone_number:{type: String},
       phone_type:{type: String}
    }],
    emails:[{
       email_address:{type: String},
       email_type:{type: String}
    }]
});
```

I simplified the schemas above, but they essentially represent the structure of what I'm dealing with.

My challenge is in the ExpressJs/Mongoose API, where I want to pass the object and update the subdocuments.

Here is how I thought it would be done, but this does not work:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var vCard = require('vcards-js');

router.route('/addcontact/:ownerId')

.put(function(req, res){

  Profile.findOne({'owner_id':req.params.ownerId}, function(err, profile){

    if(err)
      res.send(err);

    profile.contacts.push({
      first_name : req.body.first_name,
      last_name : req.body.last_name
    })

    req.body.phones.forEach(function(phone, index, arr){
      profile.contacts.phones.push({
        phone_type:phone.phone_type,
        phone_number:phone.phone_number
      })
    })

    req.body.emails.forEach(function(email, index, arr){
      profile.contacts.emails.push({
        email_type:email.email_type,
        email_address:email.email_address
      })
    })

    profile.save(function(err){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(profile);
    })

  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

So to clarify, I have an existing "User Profile" record.
The user schema has a "contacts" array to hold multiple contacts.
Each contact has phone and email arrays so each contact record can hold multiple emails and phone numbers.

What I'm trying to do is .PUT contact records and update the user Profile document.

Thanks for any sage advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` model doesn't seem to have `owner_id`. Assuming that it is missed out here and you wanted to add a new contact to the existing user.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Profile = require('../models/profile');

router.route('/addcontact/:ownerId').put(function (req, res) {
  var phones = req.body.phones;
  console.log('phones', phones);

  var emails = req.body.emails;
  console.log('emails', emails);

  var contacts = {
    contact_name: req.body.first_name,
    contact_age: '25',
    emails: emails,
    phones: phones
  };

  Profile.findOneAndUpdate({
    owner_id: req.params.ownerId
  }, {
    $push: {
      contacts: contacts
    }
  }, {
    new: true
  }, (err, profile) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }
    return res.json(profile);
  });

});


module.exports = router;
```

And, one minor change I made to your code is adding `return` when sending response to avoid further execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var phonesArray = req.body.phones;
var emailsArray = req.body.emails;

Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
{'owner_id':req.params.ownerId}
{phones: {$push: {$each: phonesArray}}, emails: {$push: {$each: emailsArray }}}, function(err, profile){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);

    console.log(profile);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jackson, tried your code, but I just blank arrays. Am I missing something? I can console.log and see that the arrays are being passed...

Comment: empty arrays are phonesArray and emailsArray? or in db after update?

Comment: pls write your code, with console.log, and results of log here.

Comment: but If you found a solution, do not answer this messages